# How to rearrange a dataset to make facet graphing more easily done (original dataset combines two datasets)?

Tags: r, dataframe, graph, facet

I been trying to find some resources similar to this but my current dataset looks like this:

| lwg_date | bon_date | lwg_length | bon_length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| May | April | 1 | 31 |
| May | April | 10 | 14 |
| May | April | 12 | 12 |
| March | May | 19 | 11 |
| April | May | 5 | 17 |

and from the examples I see for facet graphs, an ideal format seems to be like this:

| Type | date | length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LWG | May | 1 |
| BON | April | 31 |
| LWG | May | 10 |
| BON | April | 24 |
| LWG | May | 12 |

...and so on...

I have been trying with R's rearrangement functions, tried something with facet wraps, and have tried using loops and if statements. However, I still have been unable to figure this out so my questions are:

1. This new format would make facet graphs easier, correct? (date, length, and count of overlapping histograms.) I struggled to do such a graph with the older data but perhaps I'm being going about it wrong.
2. If this new dataset is better, what would be a good method?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're referring to the concept of **Tidy Data** (see: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html), and the easiest method to get there is probably to use `tidyr`'s `pivot_longer`:

```r
library(tidyr)

df <-
  df |>
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_sep = "_", names_to = c("type", ".value"))
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 10 × 3
   type  date  length
   <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
 1 lwg   May        1
 2 bon   April     31
 3 lwg   May       10
 4 bon   April     14
 5 lwg   May       12
 6 bon   April     12
 7 lwg   March     19
 8 bon   May       11
 9 lwg   April      5
10 bon   May       17
```

This could easily allow for faceted plotting with `ggplot`:

E.g.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df |>
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = length)) + 
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~ type)
```

Output:

[image]

Data:

```r
library(readr)

df <-
read_table("lwg_date    bon_date    lwg_length  bon_length
May April   1   31
May April   10  14
May April   12  12
March   May 19  11
April   May 5   17")
```